# Dynamically create nested CSS

Tags: javascript, php, css, scope

I want to create a kind of 'scope' in CSS, so that all the CSS in a particular style tag does only effect a specific html node.

Simpler: I want something like this:

```
<style id="style1">
  .foo { color: red; }
  .bar { color: green; }
</style>
<style id="style2">
  .dor { color: blue; }
</style>
```

dynamically turn into something like this:

```
<style id="style1">
  #scope1 .foo { color: red; }
  #scope1 .bar { color: green; }
</style>
<style id="style2">
  .dor { color: blue; }
</style>
```

With PHP or JavaScript (preferably using jQuery)

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: If you rewrite the CSS with JS, you have to pay attention that the CSS isn't parsed and rendered twice – first in its original format and a second time after the rewrite. It would be much better to that on the server and deliver the complete CSS…

Comment: That is very much true, rewriting the CSS with PHP seems like the best option. The only question remains how to do this elegantly and without the possibility to create errors in the CSS code..

Comment: "without the possibility to create errors in the CSS code" Use a CSS preprocessor like suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything that would do that specifically, but I would suggest looking into [sass/scss](http://sass-lang.com/). It provides a similar way of nesting css (and much more)

eg.

```
#style1 {
  .foo {
    color: red;
  }
  .bar {
    color: green;
  }
}
#style2 {
  .dor { color: blue; }
}
```

Comment: Nice! this has exactly the functionality that I am looking for. But because I need the preprocessing of Sass to happen at the moment I request a web page (with different (S)CSS code every time) it is all getting a bit complicated. Then I would need to create a temporary SCCS file, and do a separate (ajax)request to that file in order to pre process it and get the right code..

Comment: @oogie "I need the preprocessing of Sass to happen at the moment I request a web page (with different (S)CSS code every time)" That sounds like a very strange requirement. Of course the CSS should only be rendered after each change to the sources. If you do that on each page call, you might get performance problems. For example the page is delivered to the user, but the CSS files wasn't rendered yet…